# Finding the limit using $\lim_{x\to 0} (\sin x)/x = 1$ identity

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I was having trouble with a question that asked me to utilize the $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ identity. It looks like  $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2} }$ $\frac{\tan 2x }{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}$. I 'm not sure how I would utilize the identity in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Already tried $\tan(a) = \sin(a)/\cos(a)$?

Comment: **Hint:** Which substitution you should use so that your  limit takes the form $\lim\limits_{n\to0}$?

Comment: also put $y = x - \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get

$\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\tan(2u+\pi)}{u}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin(2u+\pi)}{u\cos(2u+\pi)}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{-\sin2u}{u\cdot(-1)}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac {2\sin u\cos u}{u}=2\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{sin u}{u}\cos u=2$.

Comment: How did you get rid of the + pi on the top on the third step?

Comment: I used $\sin(2u+\pi)=\sin 2u\cos\pi+\cos 2u\sin\pi$.

Comment: Alright. I think I understand that. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome - if you want me to try to explain anything else, let me know.